# Why I can't call the initial function when I assign the initial function(a function declaration) to a variable?

Tags: javascript, recursion, function-expression

I'm learning javaScript through the book" *Professional JavaScript for Web developers 3rd Edition*". And In section 7.1 of Chapter 7, the author puts an example to realize the decoupling between executing function and the function name:

```js
var factorial = (function f(num) {
    if (num <= 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return num * f(num - 1);
    }
});
```

The code above does well whether in strict mode or not.
As I saw before, the code worked in two steps:

First: declare the function f

```
function f(num) {
    if (num <= 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return num * f(num - 1);
    }
}
```

Second: assign the function name f to the variable factorial

```
var factorial = f;
```

So I thought it's feasible to call the function f directly in the example below.

```js
var factorial = (function f(num) {
    if (num <= 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return num * f(num - 1);
    }
});

f(5);
```

But in fact, it doesn't work. The console said "f is not a function";
Why? Is there any thing to do with closure?

Comment: You've got a typo - you haven't closed the `else` block in your function.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I corrected it and re-edited  the question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

`var factorial = function f(){};` is not the same as `function f(){} var factorial = f;`

When using function expressions you can only access the function by the name you gave it from inside the function.

```js
var factorial = function f(num) {
    if (num <= 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return num * f(num - 1);
    }
};
console.log(typeof f);
console.log(factorial(5));
```

If you first define the function and then assign it to a variable then the function will be accessible using both names by everyone in the scope.

```js
function f(num) {
    if (num <= 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return num * f(num - 1);
    }
};

var factorial = f;
console.log(typeof f);
console.log(factorial(5));
```

In the first example `f` does not get hoisted. The name `f` only exists inside the function. In the second example `f` gets hoisted. The name `f` exists in the global scope.

Comment: Appreciate your answer! Thanks.

Comment: @chenxy If the answer solved your problem you can accept it by clickin on the arrow at the top left